# How to use React Highligher

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a text editor that stores edited
value in a state called "value"
like shown below. When I show a preview of the text it comes like this

```js
<p>This is the value intially</p>
```

So I'm using parse(value) to render content correctly.

Now when I'm using react Highlighter document as per instruction [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words) and passing this parsed value.

I'm not getting anything.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState('This is the value intially');

const getValue =() => {
    return <div>{parse(value)}</div>
}
</div>
  <Highlighter
    highlightClassName="YourHighlightClass"
    searchWords={["and", "or", "the"]}
    autoEscape={true}
    textToHighlight={getValue}
  />
</div>
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, The `texttoHighlight` doesn't have JSX value and also the string lies inside like this.

I made this change.

```js
const getValue =()=>{
   return parse(value).props.children
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you need to provide a string value to `textToHighlight`

Like:

```js
<p>
  <Highlighter
    highlightClassName="YourHighlightClass"
    searchWords={["and", "or", "the"]}
    autoEscape={true}
    textToHighlight="This is the value intially"
  />
</p>
```